# Output text file content to JSON Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, text-files

**I would like to output the following text file to the JSON format displayed below using Python.**

I am not sure where to begin, but I hope that my problem is simple to understand.

input.txt

```
Name 1, FeatureServer, thisIsALink, layer 1, layer 2
Name 2, FeatureServer, thisIsALink, layer 1
Name 3, MapServer, thisIsALink, layer 1, layer 2
Name 4, FeatureServer, thisIsALink, layer 1, layer 2
Name 5, FeatureServer, thisIsALink, layer 1, layer 2, layer 3
```

output.json

```
{
    "Name 1": {
        "type": "FeatureServer",
        "url": "thisIsALink",
        "layer(s)": {
            "1": "layer 1",
            "2": "layer 2"
        }
    },
    "Name 2": {
        "type": "FeatureServer",
        "url": "thisIsALink",
        "layer(s)": {
            "1": "layer 1"
        }
    },
    "Name 3": {
        "type": "FeatureServer",
        "url": "thisIsALink",
        "layer(s)": {
            "1": "layer 1",
            "2": "layer 2"
        }
    },
    "Name 4": {
        "type": "FeatureServer",
        "url": "thisIsALink",
        "layer(s)": {
            "1": "layer 1",
            "2": "layer 2"
        }
    },
    "Name 5": {
        "type": "FeatureServer",
        "url": "thisIsALink",
        "layer(s)": {
            "1": "layer 1",
            "2": "layer 2",
            "3": "layer 3"
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried following a tutorial from GeeksforGeeks

But I haven't quite figured out how to make it work for my situation.

Comment: "I have tried following a tutorial from GeeksforGeeks"—GeeksForGeeks is garbage, but... what tutorial? Did you forget to include a link?

Comment: Could you show what you tried and which part exactly you don't understand? is it how to read from a file? `f = open('myfile.csv')`. is it how to split the string into substrings? `s = "abc, def, ghi".split(", ")`. Is it working with json files? `import json` then `my_json_string = json.dumps(python_dictionary_that_you_have_to_construct)`. Is it writing to a file? On Stack Overflow it is better to give more details and focus on a single problem, if you want to get a focused and detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small script that does just that:

```
import json

output = {}
with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        # Split the line, preserve all layers
        name, server, url, *layers = line.rstrip().split(", ")
        output[name] = {
            "type": server,
            "url": url,
            "layer(s)": {str(i): layer for i, layer in enumerate(layers, 1)}
        }

with open("output.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(output, f, indent=4)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is one way to do it, based on the infromation you've provided:

```
import json

def main():
    file = './74724498/input.txt'
    output_dict = {}
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            # Strip the newline character and split the line into a list
            line_ls = line.strip().split(", ")
            # Create a dictionary for each row:
            row_dict = {
                line_ls[0]: {
                    "type": line_ls[1],
                    "url": line_ls[2],
                    # Create a dictionary for each layer:
                    "layer(s)": {str(index): val for index, val in enumerate(line_ls[3:], start=1)}
                    }
                }
            # Update the output dictionary with the row dictionary:
            output_dict.update(row_dict)
        
        # Write the output dictionary to a json file, indenting the output for readability:
        json_string = json.dumps(output_dict, indent=4)
        # Write the json string to a file:
        with open('json_data.json', 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.write(json_string)    
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Play with it, see if that is what you're looking for!

Answer (score -3):

The problem is that your "layers" need to be nested in json, and there's no way to represent that in csv. If it is implied that columns 4, 5 (and beyond) should be nested, you could address that programmatically.

I assume this is the tutorial you are referring to :

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-csv-to-json-using-python/

Comment: This feels better suited to a comment than an answer.

Comment: What does it have to do with CSV?